# extjs dynamically add paramters to baseparams of store

Tags: extjs

i am trying to follow this example here :http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?11735-How-can-I-ADD-to-baseParams-rather-than-overwrite-one-set-of-baseParams-with-another
The objective is to add parameters to your baseparams dynamically.
But when I submit request, I cannot see the parametrs added. What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every class extending `Ext.data.Store` has a `setBaseParam()` method that can be used for that.

If your store is for example in variable called `store` you do

```
store.setBaseParam('someParameter','value');
```

Probably the most common usage is in grids

```
grid.getStore().setBaseParam('someParameter','value');
```

similarily in remote comboboxes

```
comboBox.getStore().setBaseParam('someParameter','value');
```

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more?Ext.data.Store--> How does this know which store I am pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

for ExtJS4 you should do

comboBox.getStore().getProxy().extraParams.someParam = 'someValue'